# Saxon-CE Installing problems

Tags: client-side, saxon

I'm trying to use Saxen-CE. But when I run the following  code with Eclipse on my localhost I receive 2 Errors:

- Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'
  CECE12D2976993D3B12B21ED2115A689.cache.html:1
- Error: Permission
  denied to access property 'Saxonce'
  CECE12D2976993D3B12B21ED2115A689.cache.html:2042

I tried to change the permissions but without success. Am I missing something? Even when I import Saxonce.nocache.js directly I'm not able to call the Saxon.run function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Saxonce/Saxonce.nocache.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var onSaxonLoad = function() {
        Saxon.run(
        {
          stylesheet: "transformation.xsl",
          source:     "xmlfile.xml",
          logLevel:   "INFO"
        })};
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    TEST
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any other XSLT 2.0 Processor? Maybe jquery?

Comment: I don't have any experience running client-side code in Eclipse. Have you tried running it directly in a browser?

Comment: No I only installed a localhost with eclipse, what do you mean directly?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understand what you are doing. Just tell us whether it works if you take Eclipse out of the equation.

Comment: I got it work with Eclipse. There is a problem with the onSaxonLoad problem what I don't understand, if i set an Interval before Saxon.run it works perfectly!